# Boolean in Java condition

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, boolean

I have an issue, I have a method which is an action performed. If the checkbox is ticked then additional fields become available. If not ticked then they are greyed out. So basically what I want is to add to this method. I have a first condition and now need to add a second condition to it. I pasted the code snippet below, basically what I need is to put it into an if else, but I get some errors. Any advise is much appreciated.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean sel = _useSSL.isSelected();
    _port.setUseSSL(sel);
    _keystore.setEnabled(sel);
    _passphrase.setEnabled(sel);
    L_KEYSTORE.setEnabled(sel);
    L_PASSPHRASE.setEnabled(sel);
}
```

Above is the working method, now I need to add in if _truststore.isSelected();   then execute something else.

How can I add this second Boolean condition to the method?

Comment: You really have bad variable naming here...

Comment: Oh ya sorry I forgot to mention, they cannot be && or ||, because they serve different purposes.

Comment: Basically they need to be independent of each other, ssl is for something and truststore is for something else

Comment: *"Now I need to add in if _truststore.isSelected(); then execute something else"* So what is prevent you from writing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it just like you have used 'sel' in "actionPerfomed" method like this:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean sel = _useSSL.isSelected();
    _port.setUseSSL(sel);
    _keystore.setEnabled(sel);
    _passphrase.setEnabled(sel);
    L_KEYSTORE.setEnabled(sel);
    L_PASSPHRASE.setEnabled(sel);
    boolean trus = _truststore.isSelected();
    //Use trus for the other things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it by building a method per boolean and binding them to one "action performed" method like this:

```
public void actionPerformedForUseSSL(boolean useSSL) {
    _port.setUseSSL(useSSL);
    _keystore.setEnabled(useSSL);
    _passphrase.setEnabled(useSSL);
    L_KEYSTORE.setEnabled(useSSL);
    L_PASSPHRASE.setEnabled(useSSL);
}

public void actionPerformedForTrustStore(boolean trustStore) {
    _port.setTrustStore(trustStore);
    _a.setEnabled(trustStore);
    _b.setEnabled(trustStore);
    _c.setEnabled(trustStore);
}

//Fire this when action performed
public void actionPerformed() {
    boolean sel = _useSSL.isSelected();
    boolean trust = _trustStore.isSelected();

    actionPerformedForUseSSL(sel);
    if(trust) {
        actionPerformedForTrustStore(trust);
    }
}
```

Add or remove or mix any fields with this structure easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following piece of code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    boolean sel = _useSSL.isSelected();

    _port.setUseSSL(sel);
    _keystore.setEnabled(sel);
    _passphrase.setEnabled(sel);
    L_KEYSTORE.setEnabled(sel);
    L_PASSPHRASE.setEnabled(sel);

    boolean selOther= _truststore.isSelected();
    if(selOther){
     //perform task if the _truststore is selected
    }
}
```